# AWS "Lambda" Needing More CPU/RAM - Trigger EC2 "Job?"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a daily process that needs to digest a tremendous amount of data from two external sources.  It normally requires around 28GB or RAM, and a decent amount of processing power.  Due to this, an AWS Lambda won't work.

In the meantime, I've been running the process on an EC2 instance.  In order to save resources, I've attempted to start the instance using a CloudWatch event.  Since no event exists for "StartEC2," I'm kicking off a AWS Lambda instead, which in turn starts the EC2 isntance using Amazon support libraries.

All of this is extremely cumbersome, and I've been looking for a library or pattern that can do what I want.  Essentially, I need to start an EC2 instance on a cron/event, deliver a unit of work to it (Shell Script, Java App, whatever), have it run it, then shutdown.

I'd love any suggestions for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into AWS Systems Manager (SSM), you can create an Automation document that will launch the instance, run any custom scripts or tasks, and shut it down again when you're done. You can trigger the SSM Automation with a cron schedule via CloudWatch Events.

You may also want to consider AWS Batch for this type of workload.

Comment: This looks great for running a script.  However, I'm having a hard time finding a way to start an EC2 node that is stopped.  Are you saying I should launch a completely new instance instead?

Comment: I just found this tutorial.  I didn't realize you could run as Python.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-walk-document-builder.html